# "it was intended decision" vs. "it was an intended decision"

Tags: grammar, meaning

> "it was intended decision" vs. "it was an intended decision"

1. Do they both are grammatically correct?
2. If so, is there a difference in meaning?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, if the "decision" is known/made (which I think it is) then it is something specific. In that case, you need the definite article "the".

Answer (score 1):

There are certain situations where we do not use articles. Among them are, before plural countable nouns, before uncountable or abstract nouns, before proper nouns, etc.. A full list can be fount on [Englishgrammar.org](https://www.englishgrammar.org/omission-articles/).

"Intended decision" does not come under any of those. Therefore, grammatically speaking, the use of an article would be considered correct.
The question remains, which one to use.

You cannot use "the" if the decision is known/made as it would make the sentence about something specific. (As advised by AIQ in the comment). Or you may choose to use "an" if the sentence isn't about any specific decision.